# jQuery autocomplete UI with servlet is not returning any data

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets, jquery-autocomplete

I have been fiddling with this code fragment from past few hours but I am unable to understand how jQuery's autocomplete UI works. I followed this tutorial http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery/
I used same example but instead of sending request to a JSP, I used a servlet. The request reaches  the servlet "Fetcher", it executes as well but nothing is returned to the page. Here's the code.

```
public class Fetcher extends HttpServlet {
    [...]

    List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String param = request.getParameter("term");

    countryList.add("USA");
    countryList.add("Pakistan");
    countryList.add("Britain");
    countryList.add("India");
    countryList.add("Italy");
    countryList.add("Ireland");
    countryList.add("Bangladesh");
    countryList.add("Brazil");
    countryList.add("United Arab Emirates");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
     for(String country : countryList){
        out.println(country);
    }

    [...]
}
```

Javascript fragment in HTML:

```html
 <script>
       $(function() {

         $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: "Fetcher"

      });
 });
 </script>
```

HTML form:

```html
 <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
 <input id="tags" />
```

The examples on the page seems written for a pro in jquery,  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default . Please, could someone tell how exactly it works, so that I can use it in other places.

Comment: The tutorial which you found shows to use `$("#tags").autocomplete("url")`, but you're using it as `$("#tags").autocomplete({source:"url"})`. If you're doing it differently from the tutorial for some reason, why are you complaining that it didn't work? You should be using `$("#tags").autocomplete("Fetcher")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **servlet** should return the autocomplete data as JSON. There a several options, I have opted for an array which contains an object with label/value properties:

```
@WebServlet("/autocomplete/*")
public class AutoCompleteServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

        final List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
        countryList.add("USA");
        countryList.add("Pakistan");
        countryList.add("Britain");
        countryList.add("India");
        countryList.add("Italy");
        countryList.add("Ireland");
        countryList.add("Bangladesh");
        countryList.add("Brazil");
        countryList.add("United Arab Emirates");
        Collections.sort(countryList);

        // Map real data into JSON

        response.setContentType("application/json");

        final String param = request.getParameter("term");
        final List<AutoCompleteData> result = new ArrayList<AutoCompleteData>();
        for (final String country : countryList) {
            if (country.toLowerCase().startsWith(param.toLowerCase())) {
                result.add(new AutoCompleteData(country, country));
            }
        }
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(result));
    }
}
```

to return the autocomplete data, you could use this helper class:

```
class AutoCompleteData {
    private final String label;
    private final String value;

    public AutoCompleteData(String _label, String _value) {
        super();
        this.label = _label;
        this.value = _value;
    }

    public final String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public final String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

so in the servlet, the real data is mapped into a form suitable for jQuery's autocomplete. I have selected Google GSON to serialize the result as JSON.

Related:

- [Understanding and Implementing Jquery autocomplete with AJAX source and appendTo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11730034/2390083)
- [How do you return a JSON object from a Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2023209/2390083)

---

As for the **HTML document** (implemented in a .jsp), pick the correct libraries, stylesheets and styles:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="autoComplete.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <div class="ui-widget">
                <label for="country">Country: </label>
                <input id="country" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Related: [jQuery autocomplete demo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

---

I have put the **Javascript functions** in a separate file `autoComplete.js`:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#country").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/your_webapp_context_here/autocomplete/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { term: request.term },

                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
               });              
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

The autocomplete function uses an AJAX request to call the servlet. As the result of the servlet is suitable, it can be used as-is for the response.

Related:

- [What are the “response” and “request” arguments in jQuery UI Autocomplete's “source” callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9934098/2390083)
- [jQuery autocomplete widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete)
- [jQuery ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)